# how can i rotate my screen shot image in IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie in IPhone programming.I was sending one of my views screen shot as email.How can i rotate my screen shot image to 270 degree to make it suitable for me ? Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your image in UIImageview and try.

```
myImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(270);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the photo in Preview, find "rotate right"/"rotate left" in the tools menu.

This question would be better asked on supper user -- stack overflow is reserved for programing or near programing questions.